# fread file which has abnormal value and R session aborted

Tags: r, exception, try-catch, fread

I am trying to fread a 80 csv files of size 350 to 400MB( not at the same time). I have used trycatch for exception handling i.e if any one file has abnormal values then to proceed with the loop, but either it is not executing the rest of the loop or it is showing session aborted and restarting R session.

The below code throws no error but does not execute completely.

```
 Today <- Sys.Date()
 for(k in 1:length(Dir)){
  for(i in 1:length(server_name)){
  setwd(Dir[[k]])
  myFiles <- list.files(pattern= server_name[i])
  Data <- data.table()
  Data <- tryCatch ((fread(myFiles,sep=",",header=TRUE,showProgress = TRUE,verbose=TRUE,fill=TRUE)), error= function(err){
  errMess <- paste0("Not available -" , myFiles)
  write(errMess, "error_log.txt")
})

if (nrow(Data)!=0) {

  ##list of actions to be executed
  setwd("C:/D Drive data/Enrichment/RDS File1")
  saveRDS(Data, file = paste0(Today,"_",server_name[i], ".RDS"))
  }
  }
  Today <- Today - 1 
  }
```

If i don't handle the exceptions then it gives error R session aborted and restarts.

Comment: 1. Does it work you just read one file? 2. What do you mean exactly by `not at the same time`? 80*400MB are 32 GB...

Comment: Perhaps `errMess <- paste0("Not available -" , myFiles[i])` tells you which file is problematic, but the abort/restart suggests the session consumed all available RAM and was shut down, at least that's what happens to me.